# Dart program refusing to execute because of MIME type checking?

Tags: dart, mime-types, dartium

I've been trying to install our Client.dart web program to our server, it is referenced from an index.html file, and all has been working fine locally.

There have been a number of issues I have found my way around, but this one has me stumped.  Note: The client application is using Polymer and has some HTTP code in it. It also uses Websockets.

The EXACT message I'm now getting is:

**Refused to execute script from 'http://swarmshepherd.com:9494/client.dart' because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.**

There is a "Header" (HTTP) of: , "X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff" 
which seems to be related to the problem.  Nothing that has made sense to me
has worked yet.

Longer term we must be able to run in Chrome, but this message is happening in 
Dartium.

The message is found in the DeveloperTools/js monitor  - and it is the first and only message I'm getting.

(I thought there might be a Chomium/Dartium option to turn off strict checking but nothing shows up anywhere, and I have now tried about everything I can think of in the header section of the HTTP Code (which is most iffy and frustrating because I can get NO idea from the code how this might be used!)

Thanks in advance for any clues!

_george

Comment: What server are you using to serve your Dart script? What exactly are you deploying to your server? `pub build` creates only deployable JavaScript no deployable Dart result yet. Maybe it's easier to try to deploy the result of `pub build` first.

Comment: Looks like you have to add a MimeType for .dart Files to your webserver. In case you realy want to server .dart files instead of a pub built .js file like Günter pointed out.

Comment: Guenter, I have developed a Dart ('entry program') and have only run it from the Dart Editor in Dartium.  Yes, I did run [pub build] and it completed successfully, all the files that I think I need are in the 'web' folder as is standard procedure.   All the HTML files and more have been installed (even some libraries I haven't used for months and for which there is zero reference).    ALso I thought I'd start off by using Sinatra and serving the index.html file as this is a "Gem" I am familiar with.... a fast try using Dart did not work at all. Many thanks, AGAIN!

Comment: I have now tested that Sinatra will serve an html file with js as it is configured and it does (really basic).  Have also tried blocking out all the HTTP code in my Dart program, rerunning pub build and so on but this also does not work.

Comment: @georgekoller, the results of `pub build` are placed in `build/` not `web/. See https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-build.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Sinatra (I'm guessing, based on the comments), you can [register custom mime types](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Mime%20Types):

```
configure do
  mime_type :dart, 'application/dart'
end
```

If you're using IIS, you need to add it to the `Mime Types` section in the [IIS configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx).

Other webservers should have some similar configuration options.